# How to get list of variables from a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, python-import

I am having trouble getting a list of all variables in a file, and I have tried all methods that I can find, but there isn't a way that worked for me. `dir()` would return this:

`['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']`

While working on this, I also had trouble importing a file from a variable containing the file name. I have tried `importlib.import_module(filename)`, `with open(filename, 'r') as infile: needed_file = infile.read()`, and `__import__()` was deprecated, in the end, I'm just using `with open()`.

Back to my first problem, I have tried using `getattr()`, however I got the same results as with `dir()`. These are what I have tried:

```
named_objects = dir(self.filedat)
print(named_objects)
```

```
attrs = [attr for attr in dir(self.filename) if not attr.startswith('__')]
file_objects = [getattr(self.filedat, attr) for attr in attrs]

named_objects = []
for attr in file_objects:
    if isfunction(attr):
        named_objects.append(attr.__name__)
    elif not isfunction(attr) and not isclass(attr) and not ismodule(attr) and not ismethod(attr):
        named_objects.append(attr.__name__)
print(file_objects)
```

I have also tried many variations of those, and none of which have succeeded.

**Edit:**
I am trying to get a list of all manually defined variables in said file.

Comment: What result do you expect ? Does your final removes the '__ __' ones ?

Comment: I want a list of all defined variables in the file